# Why on shutdown the SCR can be compared to a power diode?

Tags: power-electronics, thyristor, scr

I have this as a homework question and can't seem to find the answer in my notes, book or internet. I know they will behave similarly when there is a reverse polarity on both, but the way my professor phrased it seems like he is talking about the process of turning off the SCR, in which I can't think of any resemblance.

Comment: There is no "ready made" answer. The question is supposed to make you **think** about how an SCR behaves (in shutdown). So, how does an SCR in shutdown behave? And how does a (power) diode behave?

Comment: To be fair, I don't think I even understood the question exactly. Am I suppose to talk about, I think I'm supposed to talk about how their V-I curves will be similar when the voltage is negative but the way my professor phrased in my native language it seems like he is talking about the process of turning off the SCR, on which I don't think there's any resemblance, so I'm confused

Comment: Hint: it's easy to turn on an SCR using the trigger. How do you turn it off?

Comment: By keeping the current below the holding current, but I still can't see it

Comment: Think about what happens when a diode shuts off. SCR holding current is more about turning on than turning off. You don'y understand that properly.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, in the diode, on shutdown, all the extra charge in the PN junction must leave before the depletion layer is formed again, since the thyristor are just 3 PN junctions, the same must happen to it before it's depletion layer is formed again, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

The PNPN is like a PN in  Power Diode because the Vcb's cancel in the PNP+NPN.

[image]